# Android Runtime - Fatal Exception: main

Tags: android

I have an Android Run time Fatal Exception: main and I don't know what I have to do to resolve this problem. I have the following code, which causes this Exception:

```
package com.example.toggle_button;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     ToggleButton toggleButton1,toggleButton2;
      Button Submit;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



            toggleButton1=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
            toggleButton2=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
            Submit =(Button)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                       StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();  
                       result.append("ToggleButton1 : ").append(toggleButton1.getText());  
                       result.append("\nToggleButton2 : ").append(toggleButton2.getText());  
                    //Displaying the message in toast  
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                }
            });

        }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

In this code after running my android project i am getting an error on AVD that toggle_button unfortunately stopped and also showing fatal exception in main at run time.I am not able solve this .Please tell me suitable solution for the same.

```
This is the LogCat of Exception:


07-13 03:38:13.793: D/AndroidRuntime(1362): Shutting down VM
07-13 03:38:13.793: W/dalvikvm(1362): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
07-13 03:38:13.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):      FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 03:38:13.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.toggle_button/com.example.toggle_button.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
07-13 03:38:13.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
07-13 03:38:13.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
07-13 03:38:13.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-13 03:38:13.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
07-13 03:38:13.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-13 03:38:13.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-13 03:38:13.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-13 03:38:13.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 03:38:13.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-13 03:38:13.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at com.android.internal.
os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
```

Comment: answer has been given. but trying to read into the logs would help you going forward.
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button

Comment: Please, post your xml layout here

Answer (score 4):

Logcat clearly said

> : threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x41465700) 07-13 03:38:13.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main 07-13 03:38:13.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.toggle_button/com.example.toggle_button.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast
>   to android.widget.Button

Going wrong over here

```
 Submit =(Button)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Do like

```
 Submit =(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonIdHere);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're casting a TextView to a Button:

`ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button`

To fix this issue you either need to change your cast:

```
 TextView Submit;

 Submit =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

or change the UI type in the `layout.xml` file to a `Button`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to illegal `typecasting`:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: `android.widget.TextView` cannot be **cast** to `android.widget.Button`

Either use this if your `View` is `Button`:

```
Button Submit;
Submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

or use this if your `View` is indeed a `TextView`

```
TextView textSubmit;
textSubmit = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

This is the inheritance:

- `java.lang.Object` Main Class

  - `android.view.View`

    - `android.widget.TextView`

      - `android.widget.Button`

So, `Button` extends the `TextView`.